# Next.js and Firebase keep getting serialization error when trying to read one doc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

As the title says, I'm trying to build out a blog site and I have most of it done expect for clicking on a post stub to read the full post. I keep getting this error anytime I go to the post page.

> Error: Error serializing `.post` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/posts/[slug]".
> Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

I've searched everywhere to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong but can't seem to find the right answer.

Here is by firebase code.

```
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  getFirestore,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  getDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { Timestamp, toJSON } from "firebase/firestore";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAB4SbXl-I1TMoa31ybnCzmTASXjZFnMAg",
  authDomain: "personal-blog-8decb.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "personal-blog-8decb",
  storageBucket: "personal-blog-8decb.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "473768411808",
  appId: "1:473768411808:web:c464d23c531b8bdaa4bfc5",
  measurementId: "G-6F04591W4N",
};

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const db = getFirestore();

//Reads all the posts in the database
export const getPosts = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("date", "desc"));
  const querySnapShot = await getDocs(q);
  const posts = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
    date: doc.data().date?.toDate().getTime(),
  }));
  return posts;
};

// Get one post from database based on the slug.
export const getPostBySlug = async (slug) => {
  const docRef = doc(db, "posts", `${slug}`);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    return docSnap.data();
  } else {
    console.log("No Such Document");
  }
};

// Adds posts to the database
export const createPost = async (post) => {
  await setDoc(doc(db, "posts", `${post.slug}`), {
    title: post.title,
    content: post.content,
    date: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
  });
};

export const auth = getAuth();
export const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

And here is the slug page.

```
import { async } from "@firebase/util";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getPostBySlug } from "../../lib/firebase";
import moment from "moment";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const post = await getPostBySlug();

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
}

export default function PostPage({ post }) {
  <div className="post">
    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
    <span>Published {moment(post.date).format("LL")}</span>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }}></p>
  </div>;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  What is the value of `post`?

Comment: Yes, console logs come back undefined which makes no sense to me. So there seems to be an issue fetching the doc from firestore.

Comment: It would be good if you edit the question to explain the debugging you've done so far, and give some instructions on how to reproduce the issue.  This includes showing the contents of your database, and explaining what you expect the code to do if it were to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I actually got it to work by doing a custom query for the slug and using querysnapshot instead of just doing a document reference.

Comment: Can you post your solution. So, it might be helpful to other community members.

Comment: My solution is posted, thanks for the reminder. I meant to do it yesterday and got sidetracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how I got it to work. First I changed the firebase read file to a custom query.

```
// Get one post from database based on the slug.
export const getPostBySlug = async (slug) => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "posts"), where("slug", "==", `${slug}`));
  const querySnapShot = await getDocs(q);
  const post = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
    date: doc.data().date?.toDate().getTime(),
  }));
  return post;
```

I had to do it this way because of the timestamp I used with firestore. I couldn't figure out any other way to serialize it to json.

Next I changed the getServerSideProps function in the slug js file to take a context query.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const post = await getPostBySlug(context.query.slug);
  console.log("this is the severside props: ", post);

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
}
```

After that it worked fine. There are probably better approached to this but this is what worked for me.